# Is it possible to hide/show Kendo grid column based on user role?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo ui grid in asp.net MVC. Is it possible to hide/show grid column based on user role? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify if a column is visible using [hidden](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.hidden), so one option may be to set a variable based on the users role. For example, in the controller

```
ViewBag.CanDisplay = true; // or omit if the user does not have permission
```

and in the view

```
var canDisplay = '@ViewBag.CanDisplay' | false;
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "firstProperty" },
    { field: "anotherProperty", hidden: !canDisplay }    
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is it secure using viewbag for hide a column ?

Comment: Just as secure as any other property of your model, although IMHO its always better practice to use a view model (including the `bool CanDisplay` property) rather than `ViewBag`.

Comment: #StephenMuecke thanks for reply. Can you please explain how can do this using view model . I add a property in my view model but if i add like this { field: "anotherProperty", hidden: !canDisplay } it is not working

Comment: I would still assign the value to a javascript variable if only because it makes it a little easier to read and debug - `var canDisplay = '@Model.CanDisplay' === 'True';`

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way is:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Id);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
        if(User.IsInRole("Admin")) {
            columns.Bound(p => p.AdminOnlyInfo);
        }
    })
    ...
)
```

Comment: Is `.Coulmns()` method receiving an array of `Column` object? If yes, you can create the array normally and simply pass it at the end as parameter

Comment: @j4ro Thanks for reply.i am using js version not mvc server version.